# JQuery show() after hide()

Tags: jquery, text, hide, show

HTML:

```
<table id="table1">
    <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="table1column1"><input type="text" id="idInput1" /></td>
        <td class="table1column2"><input type="text" id="idInput2" /></td>
        <td class="table1column3"><input type="text" id="idInput3" /></td>
        </tr>
</table>
<button>Hide-Text-Show</button>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        $('#idInput1').hide();
        $('.table1column1').text('Test');
        $('#idInput1').show();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QNxyG/

I don't understand why when I add a text in td element, the show() method doesn't work?

Thanks

Comment: The answers below are correct, but in the future if you want to find out for your self what happens, then I suggest using for example firebug in firefox or Developer tools in Chrome or IE.

Comment: I finally chose this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/QNxyG/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/QNxyG/4/

with .text() you override anything in your example... so the input doesnt exist anymore

HTML

```
<table id="table1">
    <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="table1column1"><span class="text" style="display:none;"></span><input type="text" id="idInput1" /></td>
        <td class="table1column2"><span class="text" style="display:none;"></span><input type="text" id="idInput2" /></td>
        <td class="table1column3"><span class="text" style="display:none;"></span><input type="text" id="idInput3" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button>Hide-Text-Show</button>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        var input = $('#idInput1');
        var text = input.parent('td').find('.text');
        text.text('text');
        text.toggle();
        input.toggle();
    });
});​
```

Comment: So, how can I toggle (hide/show) input and text inside td? For example: the first click hide input and show text, the second one show input and hide text?

Comment: have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/QNxyG/4/... put a empty span with display none and a classname and use toggle() instead of show and hide

Answer (score 4):

Because with `.text()` you overwrite the `#idInput1` element (*it gets removed*) so the next `$('#idInput1')` does not find an element to show..

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document)
    .ready(function () {
    $('button')
        .click(function () {
        $('#idInput1')
            .hide(function () {
            $('.table1column1 input')
                .val('Test', function () {
                $('#idInput1')
                    .show();
            });
        });
    });
});
```